# How to display number with dynamic fraction part length in currency mode only with "n" symbols carrying info

Tags: javascript

I have these possible values

```
12.000000349867394345466
 0.00000000231343500000001
 0.00000123364378
 0.2300000000000000000000000
```

that I want to display in such format:

```
$12.00000034
 $0.0000000023
 $0.0000012
 $0.23
```

Rounding isn't important. I just want to have two digits that carry information, but not two fixed digits after the point.
Is it possible to do with Intl.NumberFormat or similar tool without native math and reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `number.toFixed(decimalPlaces)` (which converts the number into a string with fixed decimal places) then use `parseFloat(numString)` to convert the number string with the right decimal places into a float (i.e. a number). See example below:

```js
const number = 12.000000349867394345466;
const decimalPlaces = 10;
console.log(parseFloat(number.toFixed(decimalPlaces)));
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what "decimalPlaces" I should use, even in your example it gives "12.0000003499", so, you need adjust decimalPlaces to "8" to make it worked. But in such case it won't work for numbers with 10 zero after point for example.

Answer (score 0):

Turn each value into a string, split them by `.` into their integer and fractional parts. If there wasn't a fractional part, then the value is a whole number. If there is a fractional part, we can use regex to match only what we want: leading zeroes and then two significant figures:

```js
const values = [
12.000000349867394345466,
 0.00000000231343500000001,
 0.00000123364378,
 0.2300000000000000000000000,
 1, // testing whole numbers
]

for (const value of values) {
    const [integer, fraction] = value.toString().split(".");
   
    const result = fraction ? `$${integer}.${fraction.match(/^(0*[1-9][0-9])/)[0]}` : `$${integer}`;
    
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to separate your integer and your fractional part.

Then, on the fractional part, extract the power 10 mantissa and exponent (like for scientific notation).

Round the mantissa to the significant digits needed.

And assemble back the rounded mantissa, the exponent and the integer part.

```
function significantFractRound(number,numOfSignificantDigits) {
  let intpart = Math.trunc(number);
  let fracpart = number - intpart;
  let [mantissapart, exponentpart] = (fracpart.toExponential() + '').split("e");
  let significantRounding = 10 ** (numOfSignificantDigits-1);
  let mantissarounded = Math.round(parseFloat(mantissapart)*significantRounding)/significantRounding;
  let exponent = parseInt(exponentpart);
  return intpart+(mantissarounded*(10**exponent));
}
```